# Get a list of cities around a city with a given radius with google places api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using google places api for autocomplete on a RoR project.
I want to get a list of cities around the typed city with a given radius.

For instance:

I type "Paris, France" in the input. I want to have a list (JSON or whatever) which contains all the cities around the city with a given radius (maybe 10 miles or more, it'll be a constant in the project).

How can I do that?

Thanks!

**-EDIT-**

I've end up with this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.534031,2.632121999999981&language=fr&types=locality&sensor=false&rankby=distance&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE

The lat and lng must point to a town near Paris called "Le Mee sur Seine" (https://maps.google.fr/maps?hl=fr&q=48.534031,2.632121999999981).

I want to list the towns surrouding this city ordered by distance but I have "ZERO_RESULTS" as a result...

Comment: The Maps/Places-API will not give you **all** of anything, the number of results is always limited

Comment: Yes of course, but I'll make a 10 miles or less radius around the first city so I think it'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The type you're tying to filter on, "locality" is specifically listed as not supported.  That is, Google will not let you specifically search for locality or a number of other political geo types.  See the full list of unsupported types here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types#table2